# Image width and height using carrierwave, not being saved to hstore column, although .persisted? returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, carrierwave, hstore, minimagick

ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161)

Rails 4.1.0.rc1

postgres 9.3,

using gems:

`gem 'carrierwave'` and `gem 'mini_magick'`

**The issue I got** is that for unknown reasons uploaded images width and height are not being saved to the database (although without `after :store, :set_image_geometry` facebook url and twitter url are being saved properly (using same form, same hstore column))

screencast: http://quick.as/dvvrhnjx

schema.rb - column where I want to store avatar_height and avatar_width

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.hstore   "settings",               default: {}, null: false
  end
```

avataruploader.rb

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
after :store, :set_image_geometry

...

  def set_image_geometry version
    if self.file.present? && File.exist?(self.file.path)
      img = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.file.path)
      self.model.settings['avatar_width'] = img['width']
      self.model.settings['avatar_height'] = img['height']
      binding.pry
      self.model.save
    end
  end

...
```

settings_controller.rb

```
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :remove_avatar, :avatar_cache, settings: [:facebook_url, :twitter_url, :avatar_width, :avatar_height])
  end
```

everything but saving images width and height works as intented, im attaching a part of console log:

```
    35: def set_image_geometry version
    36:   if self.file.present? && File.exist?(self.file.path)
    37:     img = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.file.path)
    38:     self.model.settings['avatar_width'] = img['width'].to_s
    39:     self.model.settings['avatar_height'] = img['height'].to_s
 => 40:     binding.pry
    41:     self.model.save
    42:   end
    43: end

[1] pry(#<AvatarUploader::Uploader70137750643660>)> self.model.settings
=> {"facebook_url"=>"",
 "twitter_url"=>"",
 "avatar_width"=>80,
 "avatar_height"=>58}
```

i tried both with .to_s and without it on img['width'], neither works

Answer (score 0):

with no changes made (checked with git diff) code started to miraculously work as supposed to

still no idea what caused the issue, therefore not marking question as answered